# How to replace multiple characters with replace function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace multiple specific character with the function replace for example :

**INPUT** :`(c#d)&(a#b)&(k>m)`

**output** : should be `#(c,d)&#(a,b)&(k>m)`

but it work only for one input  `#(c,d)&(a#b)&(k#m)`

**this is my code**

```
inr=str(input('entrer : '))    

inr = inr.replace('(a#b)','#(a,b)') or inr.replace('(c#d)','#(c,d)')
print(inr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` twice:

```
inr.replace('#',',').replace('(','#(')

#(c,d)&#(a,b)&#(k,m)
```

Comment: how about if the formula is (a>b)&(c#d)&(k|r)

Comment: you want the same change?

Comment: Yes the same change but the out put should be specific only for (c#d) ==> #(c,d) not for all formula

Comment: if you run the same code, you get undesired result?

Comment: Yes the code is applied to all the formula

Comment: I want to change only the formulas (a # b) and not the others (a> b) ..

Comment: i think the current code works. i dont understand where is it failing

Comment: the current code return (a>b)&(c#d) ==>
#(a>b)&#(c,d) it should be (a>b)&#(c,d)

Comment: try: `inr[0] + inr[1:].replace(r'#',',')
`

Comment: now it return (a,b) it must be #(a,b) ...

Comment: i fix it with inr = inr.replace('(a#b)', '#(a,b)').replace('(c#d)','#(c,d)') but it work on a specific proposition 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd'